# Unable to center text on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, text

I have a particular setup that allows 4 images set side by side and to act responsively in a list format.

I am trying to have a caption with a background matching the same height as the text and extending to the width of the image, to be centered vertically and horizontally when hovered.

I have read numerous articles where position absolute/relative is used, but I can't get it working in my code. I tried vertical align, text-center, top, left, width, but the text still remains at the bottom of the image.

Here is about 10% of the links I have clicked on:

1. [Horizontal centering text over image via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9209764)
2. [Responsive image with text overlay](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/responsive-image-with-text-overlay)
3. [Centering things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)
4. [Text over image without absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24264276)
5. [How to put text over an image without absolute positioning or setting the image as backbround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1829541)
6. [Why can't an <ul> (with absolute position) inside a <li> (with relative position) auto size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4691317)
7. [HTML: center image caption relative to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5044072)

I am sorry for the long post (Its's all the code so just skip the code to the jsfiddle).

My currrent setup [Here is a link to the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74n5qf3q/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li>
        <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover tilt" tabindex="0" data-about="Newborns"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_0095.jpg" alt="">Newborns</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover" tabindex="1" data-about="Children"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_8252.jpg" alt="">Children</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover" tabindex="2" data-about="Families"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_8607.jpg" alt="">Families</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover" tabindex="3" data-about="Lifestyle"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_6620.jpg" alt="">Lifestyle</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
/* Style the list */
ul.tab {
  whitespace: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style the a tags */
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 3);
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}


/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}


/*style the images*/
.tabimg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tab {
  font-size: 0; /* To get rid of the space below the li tags */
  display: inline-block;
  /* change this to display: block; in order to make the container as wide as the page is */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* to clear the float */
}

.tab li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.tab li a {
  width: 100%; /* remove this if you dont want the images to resize if the container is as wide as the page (if .tab is display: block;*) */
}

.tab li img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    /* Simple foreach as the js foreach method is not supported by IE9 and you may want to support it.
CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach */
function simpleForEach(array, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            callback(array[i], i);
    }
}

/* Parts of this can be done with pure css.
This function should executed on load:
    document.addEventListener("load", load);
or on DOMContentLoaded:
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load);
CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=DOMContentLoaded. */

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var tabimgs = document.getElementsByClassName("tabimg");

    // for each tabimg
    simpleForEach(tabimgs, function(tabimg) {
            var cityName = tabimg.getAttribute("data-about");

            // add the click event listener
            tabimg.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
                // onclick do:

                // hide all tabcontents
                simpleForEach(document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent"), function(tc) {
                    tc.style.display = "none";
                });

                // remove the active class
                simpleForEach(document.getElementsByClassName("tabimg"), function(ti) {
                    ti.className = ti.className.replace(" active", "");
                });

                // show the current tab, and add "active" class to the link that opened the tab
                document.getElementById(cityName);
                tabimg.className += " active";
            });
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate some help/guidance on this one please. Thank you in advance.

Incase you missed it: https://jsfiddle.net/74n5qf3q/1/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but would it be something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/74n5qf3q/2/

Comment: Thanks Aaron for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my fix: https://jsfiddle.net/JustusFT/jrhk8L7j/
I used this technique to center it. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hv3

I set the thumbnail's `position:` to relative. This causes child elements with `absolute` positioning positioned based on the parent.
New HTML:

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li>
    <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover tilt" tabindex="0" data-about="Newborns">
      <img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_0095.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">Newborns</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover" tabindex="1" data-about="Children"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_8252.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">Children</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover" tabindex="2" data-about="Families"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_8607.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">Families</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tabimg gq-module-hover" tabindex="3" data-about="Lifestyle"><img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEB_6620.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">Lifestyle</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.tab li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  /*Added*/
}
.tab li .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I also removed all instances of `text-align:center;`

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so quickly, that definitely fixed my issue. Thank you for teaching me a new skill

Comment: This actually almost completely solved a problem I was having where I needed dynamic possibly multi-line text centered over the top of an image inside an anchor.  To support multi-line I had to add a `line-height:1em` to the style which messed with the value for `top` so I had to make that `-1em`.  Except the transform values are _slightly_ off in Chrome so I had to use `-webkit-transform:translate(30%,-40%);`...any idea why?