# How do i center text on an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center text over an image of a banner.

Here is a jsfiddle of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/c6Lcr0ap/

```
HTML:

<div class="about-me">
  <div class="about-me__banner">

    <div class="about-me__banner-text">
      <h3>About Me</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="about-me__banner-image">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qiUWxdd.png">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

CSS:

h3 {
  color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to center text on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834500/unable-to-center-text-on-image)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c6Lcr0ap/1/

Comment: You need to clarify what you want. "On" the image or "over" an image and be specific in your meaning!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.about-me__banner{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.about-me__banner-text{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me">
    <div class="about-me__banner">
        <div class="about-me__banner-text">
            <h3>About Me</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="about-me__banner-image">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qiUWxdd.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually simple to do this.

first your need to absolute position the text container `.about-me__banner-text` relative to it's parent `.about-me__banner`, so it can stay over your image.

Then you can center everything inside `.about-me__banner` vertically and horizontally with flexbox, resulting in these new rules:

```css
.about-me__banner {
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about-me__banner-text {
  position: absolute;
}
```

That should do the trick. [You can check your modified fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/c6Lcr0ap/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.about-me {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: The request was for "on the image".

Comment: his question said "center text over an image" it didn't say overlaying an image

Answer (score 0):

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/fkp9g1jr/

```
.about-me__banner-text
```

class has width same as image

Answer (score 0):

If a fixed height is ok for you, here you have another solution:

```
.about-me__banner-text {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/qiUWxdd.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 57px;
    line-height: 57px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01h8tqcc/

Update:

It is probably better to split the styles like this:

```
.about-me__banner {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/qiUWxdd.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.about-me__banner-text {
  height: 57px;
  line-height: 57px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

jsfiddle: https:https://jsfiddle.net/01h8tqcc/1/