# To center text over an image, why must the container be set to position: relative?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand the purpose of using `position: relative;` to center text in a container.

Referencing this: [How do i center text on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656470/how-do-i-center-text-on-an-image)
and using this as an example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text

Both of these have the overall container set to `position: relative;` and the text to `position: absolute;`

But neither explain ***why*** the greater container needs to be set to `position: relative;` (and in fact why the text must be set to `absolute` and not `relative`).

Surely it would make more sense if the only positioning information that existed to solve this centering problem was `position: relative;` on the text element. But doing this always fails to center text correctly in a container.

What's the logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN [docs on absolute position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> …positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor…

`position: absolute` places an element at specific coordinates. Those coordinates need a positioning context. (50px from where?) Setting the container element to `position: relative` establishes the positioning context for its descendants.